# JavaScript Extend Class with hidden functions

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm having this issue today:

I'd like to extend a JavaScript Object class with some useful functions, so I wrote something like this:

```
Object.prototype.fn = function() {
    // Do some cool stuff...
};
```

Then I use another function to do a loop like this:

```
for( var i in obj ) {
    this[i] = obj[i]; // 'this' --> is another Object
    console.log( i, obj[i] );
}
```

So I moved stuff to another object from 'obj'. However, as you can see in logs, 'fn' function is now either in my extended object and in it's `__proto__`. All I want is to avoid this without using this in my 'for' loop:

```
if( typeof obj[i] !== 'function' ) // Then do it
```

So I was wondering how native functions (like toString() for example) are implemented to stay invisible outside the prototype. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method called `defineProperty` to set your property and have it not be enumerable (or as you said, stay invisible):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: 'hello'
});
```

your property `obj.test` exists (value is `hello`) but now wont be enumerable, so doing something like:

```
for(var i in obj) console.log(i);

// OR

Object.keys(obj);
```

will not print 'test', BUT you can still access it as a property (`obj.test`)

Comment: That's a nice solution! It worked for me. Thanks a lot!